# ansible : with_items inside a line with lookup

Tags: ansible

I want to ensure IP or domain is a known host::

```
- name: Ensure IP or domain is a known host
  lineinfile: >
    dest={{ home }}/.ssh/known_hosts create=yes
    state=present line="{{ lookup('pipe', 'ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa {{ item }}') }}"
  with_items:
    - 88.48.189.102
    - my.site.com
```

but the `{{item}}` is not seen inside the line={{...

I get:

```
getaddrinfo {{: Name or service not known
getaddrinfo item: Name or service not known
getaddrinfo }}: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the inner curly braces. You just have to concatenate item as a string in this way:

`{{ lookup('pipe', 'ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa ' ~ item) }}`

or

`{{ lookup('pipe', 'ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa ' + item) }}`

but the [jinja docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#math) say that the first one is the preferred method.